# Is it possible to right-click a form element to open a new page?

Tags: html, css

I created a button that I want to behave like a link but it's is not possible to right-click:

[image]

How can I make it possible to right-click the element to create a link instead of "go back" etc? The code I use now is:

```
 <form action="/ai" method="get">
    <input type="submit" class="btn primary"  name="psearchsub" value="Post your ad for free"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This particular button can be trivially converted into a link (`<a href="/ai?psearchsub=...">Post your ad</a>`) and styled with CSS to still look like a button. The problem will then have solved itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon suggest in the comment to your question,  you can style `<a>` directly. If you want right-click event, hook the `oncontextmenu` and prevent the default action:

```
<a href="http://leftclicklocation.com" id="ad">Post your ad for free</a>
<script>
  document.getElementById("ad").addEventListener("contextmenu",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // to supress the default context menu
    window.location = "http://rightclicklocation.com"; // whatever you want
  });
</script>
```

And here is the style

```
  #ad {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white; font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #6db3f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%, #54a3ee 50%, #3690f0 51%, #1e69de 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color-stop(50%,#54a3ee), color-stop(51%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6db3f2 0%,#54a3ee 50%,#3690f0 51%,#1e69de 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6db3f2', endColorstr='#1e69de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

I used [css3generator](http://css3generator.com/) and [gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I style the a directly? I don't know how to do it-

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, I think I have wrongly interpreted your post. Do you *want* to be able to right-click the button, or do you not want the user to be able to right-click the button?

*Original:*
Just a thought here - try using `oncontextmenu="return false;"` - that should prevent right-clicking if I remember correctly. (If you're willing to use a little javascript, of course)

Comment: Yes, I want it to be able to get right-clicked like a link but now it behaves like a form element.

Comment: No, `onclick="return false"` won't stop context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Put a event listener on the form element.

```
$('form').on('click', function(e){
  //detects right click
  if ( e.originalEvent.button = 2 ) {
    window.location = 'http://newpage.com'
  }
});
```

As stated below, you probably want to override the contextmenu (didn't know you could do that)

Comment: It's not working. I probably should make a fiddle for the problem.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz he is using jQuery

Comment: should be `e.originalEvent.button==2`